# How to setup a home-laptop cluster to 'practice' elasticsearch, hadoop, mesos and spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hadoop, clustering

I'd like to have elasticsearch, hadoop, mesos and spark on my home laptop (it's an 8GB with an intel i7 CPU) for practicing the setup of such frameworks and eventually to test their functions.

I'm not interested in performances, but only to practice their settigs/functionalities.

I wonder which is the easiest solution to make them work on a cluster of a few nodes (can 3 nodes be enough?). I hope it's possible to create a cluster of nodes which can be used for all the frameworks.

I've seen some tutorials on creating clusters which involve for example virtual machines or dockers.

Particularly, docker-swarm project seems interesting for my task: is this a good way to start? Or there already-built solutions for those frameworks which don't require the manual creation of a cluster?